# Get avalable time from 2 tables

Tags: sql, mysql

I have 2 tables: `availability` and `blocked_availability`.

availability:

| day | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 09:00 | 11:00 |
| 1 | 12:00 | 16:00 |

blocked_availabilty

| day | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 09:30 | 10:30 |
| 1 | 12:30 | 14:30 |

From these 2 tables combined I would like to see if there's a period of at least X minutes of availability.

In above example there some available timeslots:

09:00 - 09:30

10:30 - 11:00

12:00 - 12:30

14:30 - 16:00

Is there a query to see if there's an available timeslot of at least 60 minutes (there's only 1 in this example).

Comment: What you have tried? Please share your tried query here.

Comment: Well, I'm having troubles creating this one... I can't find a way of achieving this. So I don't have an SQL query yet.

Comment: What is precise MySQL version? In general - collect all timepoints into single list then check does each timepoint is a start of free timeslot.

Comment: I don't have the full answer to this.  But you can do something like this and move further. ```WITH RECURSIVE all_time_slots AS (
 SELECT '2000-01-01 00:00:00' AS tm
 UNION ALL
 SELECT tm + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
 FROM all_time_slots
 WHERE tm <= '2000-01-01 23:59:59')
SELECT CAST(tm AS TIME) AS tm FROM all_time_slots``` - using this you can create 30 minute time slots for the whole day. If you can try `RECURSIVE` to create similar 30-minute time slots from `availability` table, and then remove from that, 30 minute time-slots of `blocked_availability` table, something can be done or may not.

Comment: This depends on the MySQL version as well. `RECURSIVE` was added in MySQL 8 I believe. So, older versions will not support this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive `cte` to build timeslot intervals from the availability listings and then `left join` the blocked availabilties to the `cte`. Then, a ranking can performed on the rows that do not have a match in the blocked availabilities (thus it is available), and the rank values can be grouped on to find the total number of minutes per interval:

```
with recursive cte(r, day, min, end) as (
   select row_number() over (order by a.day), a.day, a.start, a.end from availability a
   union all
   select c.r, c.day, c.min + interval 1 minute, c.end from cte c where c.min < c.end
),
slots as (
   select c.day, c.r, c.min, c.end, a.start is null av from cte c 
   left join blocked_availability a on c.day = a.day and a.start < c.min and c.min < a.end
   order by c.end
),
a_slots as (
   select (select sum(s1.day = s.day and s1.min < s.min and s1.av != s.av) from slots s1) r1, s.r, s.day, s.min, s.av from slots s
)
select t.m1, t.m2 from (select a.r1, a.r, min(a.min) m1, max(a.min) m2 
    from a_slots a where a.av group by a.r1, a.r) t
where time_to_sec(timediff(t.m2, t.m1)) / 60 >= 60 -- here, specifying the number of minutes the interval must be
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/s8eiGrXZ)

Answer (score 0):

Unpivot values from both tables (here done with union all), then use lead(). This produces all possible periods from your tables. Now you can join with original data, filter "blocked" periods and count time difference.

```
with t(day, t1, t2) as (
  select day, t1, lead(t1) over (order by t1) t2 
  from (
    select day, start t1 from availability union all
    select day, end   from availability union all
    select day, start from blocked_availability union all
    select day, end   from blocked_availability ) upvt )
select t.day, t.t1, t.t2, 
       timediff(str_to_date(t.t2, '%H:%i'), str_to_date(t.t1, '%H:%i')) diff 
from t
join availability a 
  on a.day = t.day and t.t1 < a.end and a.start < t.t2
left join blocked_availability b 
  on b.day = t.day and t.t1 < b.end and b.start < t.t2
where b.day is null 
order by t.day, t.t1
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/TtLU0Rl7)